# Converting a PySpark data frame to a pandas data frame in a glue job

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, aws-glue

Is there any way to convert a PySpark data frame to a pandas data frame in a AWS glue job? The following line fails in a AWS glue job running Python 3.7 and Spark 2.4.4 but works in a jupyter notebook using the same kernel configuration:

```
df.toPandas() # df is a PySpark data frame
```

Comment: What is the error in the Glue job?

Comment: @RicS: I couldn't see any specific error. I just know that I printed a success message after the operation finished. But no success message was printed and it was taking hours to run that line when it should have taken 10 mins.

Comment: Probably you have an out of memory on the driver. Try increasing the memory allowed to the driver in your spark config. But without the logs, it is difficult to be sure